# Creating branch from a tag with maven release plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

What is the correct process for using `release:branch` to create a branch from a tag in order to create a Hotfix?  If I just checkout the tag, the plugin complains because I have a detached Head.  If I checkout the tag with a temporary branch name, then the plugin creates my new branch, but it also commits changes to my temp branch, which I really just want to delete

If I have a tag called `project-1.2.3`, I want to be able to create a new branch called `project-1.2.3-1-SNAPSHOT`.  So I check out the tag and use a command like this

`mvn release:branch -DbranchName="project-1.2.3-1-SNAPSHOT" -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false -DreleaseVersion="1.2.3-1-SNAPSHOT"`

Is there a way I can just tell it which tag that I want to create a branch off of?